# DevExtreme Data Grid with grouping column vertical Scrolling is not working

Tags: html, angular, devexpress, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I have disabled pagination in my grid i want to add vertical scrolling in data Grid with grouping column, I enable "standard" scrolling in my grid but scrolling is not showing in my grid, i am stuck in this issue kindly provide solution for this issue. here is my data grid html and attached screenshot of my grid.

```
<dx-data-grid 
   id="gridContainer"
   [dataSource]="customers"
   [allowColumnReordering]="true"
   [showBorders]="true">   
   <dxi-column dataField="CompanyName"></dxi-column>
   <dxi-column dataField="Phone"></dxi-column>
   <dxi-column dataField="Fax"></dxi-column>
   <dxi-column dataField="City"></dxi-column>
   <dxi-column dataField="State" [groupIndex]="0"></dxi-column>
    <dxo-scrolling
       mode="standard"> <!-- or "virtual" | "infinite" -->
   </dxo-scrolling>
   <dxo-search-panel [visible]="true"></dxo-search-panel>
   <dxo-paging [pageSize]="10" [enabled]="false"></dxo-paging>
   <dxo-group-panel [visible]="true"></dxo-group-panel>
   <dxo-grouping #expand [autoExpandAll]="true"></dxo-grouping>
 </dx-data-grid>
 <div class="options">
   <div class="caption">Options</div>
   <div class="option">
       <dx-check-box
           [(value)]="expand.autoExpandAll"
           text="Expand All Groups">
       </dx-check-box>
   </div>
 </div>
```

[image: Data Grid]

Answer (score 1):

After define the DataGrid ***height*** vertical scrollbar is showing in my DataGrid.

```
<dx-data-grid 
   id="gridContainer"
   [dataSource]="customers"
   [allowColumnReordering]="true"
   [showBorders]="true"
   [height]="400">
```